# Localizing based on Gender Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to globalize my app and support multiple languages, and cultures.

I have looked through the [asp.net core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) and I am wondering what is the best way to support languages with gender difference.

This is an example in one of my .en.resx file

```
<data name="FollowAcceptedMale" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>{0} now follows {1} at {2}</value>
</data>
<data name="FollowAcceptedFemale" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>{0} now follows {1} at {2}</value>
</data>
```

and in my code:

```
if (user.Gender == Gender.Male)
{
   return string.Format(localizer["FollowAcceptedMale"], followerName, followeeName , groupName);
}
else if (user.Gender == Gender.Female)
{
   return string.Format(localizer["FollowAcceptedFemale"], followerName, followeeName , groupName);
}
```

What I am currently doing is creating a phrase per gender in each language - which creates many duplicates - I would write the same phrase twice with just a different gender - or create the same exact phrase in English. The bad thing is that in the future supporting other languages with different articles, and some weird grammar that I can't really think of - will become difficult.

I am wondering if the `IStringLocalizer` supports some parameterized formating or maybe there is a better idea on how to do this.